# The text on top of my 2 UI images is not showing in storyboard

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I have a view controller (in storyboard), and in that, I have a UI image that covers the whole screen (as a background) and it is a gray color. On this background image, I have a UI Image of a logo and a UI image that is just white. Both of these (the logo and the white part) are on top of the background. On top of the white part, I have a 'username' label and a text field.

When I run the app, the username and the text field don't appear. Instead, it just shows the logo and the white part, but not the username label and the text field.

This could have to do with their being 2 UI image views on top of each other and the text on top of the both of them, but I still don't know how to fix the problem from here. Could someone please help?

Comment: Have you set constraints properly? Are you doing anything in code, or just laying the elements out in Storyboard and running it? Do the label and textView have text, or are you not seeing anything just because they have clear backgrounds and no text to display? Have you tried using `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect your UI elements?

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of those. I have moved all of the uiImages to the front of the hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen before...

When there are image views layered on top of each other, it seems that *sometimes* auto-layout renders the top-most image view *on top of* views that are on top of it (yeah, confusing with all the "on top of").

Easier way to explain:

```
- image view
  - image view
    - label
```

gets rendered as:

```
- image view
  - label
    - image view
```

I've never found an explanation for ***why***, but that is what's happening.

Couple options:

Embed your image views as subviews of a `UIView`, or

On `viewDidLoad()` explicitly bring the label and text field to the front:

```
class OrderViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var userNameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.bringSubviewToFront(userNameLabel)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(userNameTextField)
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! This helped a lot. Will I have to do this for every VC like this? And why does hierarchy not change anything with this?

Comment: You'll only need to do this for any VC where you see it happening. If your "gray" and "white" imageViews do not have images (I'm guessing you're just setting the background color), I'd recommend replacing them with plain `UIView`s. If that's not possible, you can probably get more consistency by embedding them in a "background UIView". As I said, I don't know *why* this happens, but... because I've seen it before, and it is so easy to reproduce, my guess is this is an actual "bug" (not developer error).